# error message: "int object is not callable" when trying to make a double comprehension list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a double comprehension list that looks like `[1^1, 2^1, 3^1, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 1^3, 2^3, 3^3]` until the exponent reaches `99`.

```
very_long_list=[f(i) for i in range(1,99) for f in [1,2,3]]
```

this is telling me int is not callable and I have no clue what this means...

Comment: `f(i)` means call the function `f` with the argument `i`. But obviously your `f` is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `f(i)` with the power operator, i.e. `f**i`:

```
very_long_list = [f**i for i in range(1, 99) for f in [1,2,3]]
```

This will result in:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 9, 1, 8, 27, 1, 16, 81, 1, 32, 243, 1, 64, ...
```